# Error in form validation using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing a problem in validating the form using Codeigniter. Below is the code I am using in my project.

I have followed all the rules which I have read in the Codeigniter user guide, but I don't know what that issue is; the validation is not happening.

**Controller (page.php)**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends Front_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('Page_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['page_title'] = 'Doctors Feedback';
        $data['base_url']= $this->uri->segment_array();
        
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('qualification', 'Qualification', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('residential', 'Residential Address', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('clinic', 'Clinic Address', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->view('doctors_form', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**View (doctors_form.php)**

```
<form>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name')?>" placeholder="Name">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("name");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Select Gender</label>
        <select class="form-control jcf-hidden" data-jcf="{&quot;wrapNative&quot;: false, &quot;wrapNativeOnMobile&quot;: false}">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Qualification</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qualification" name="qualification" value="<?php echo set_value('qualification')?>" placeholder="Qualification">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("qualification");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" value="<?php echo set_value('age')?>" placeholder="Age">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("age");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo set_value('date')?>" placeholder="Date">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("date");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Residential Address</label>
        <textarea rowa="5" class="form-control" id="address" name="residential" placeholder="Residential Address"></textarea>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("residential");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Clinic Address</label>
        <textarea rowa="5" class="form-control" id="address" name="clinic" placeholder="Clinic Address"></textarea>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("clinic");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email')?>" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("email");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="<?php echo set_value('mobile')?>" placeholder="Mobile">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("mobile");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo set_value('phone')?>" placeholder="Phone">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("phone");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label>Comment</label>
        <textarea rowa="5" class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("comment");?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Which error are you getting? please describe that also so we can debug that

Comment: Im not getting any errors, but the url is changing from /cms/page/index to this cms/page/index?name=&qualification=&age=&date=&residential=&clinic=&email=&mobile=&phone=&comment=&submit=

Comment: You have to set action and method attributes in <form> tag

Comment: ok action means weather i have to use the controller name or view name ? im seriously just a begginer to this field please can u be bit specific

Comment: You can set action attribute as blank , it will submit your form on same url
If you want to submit your form in another url then you have to put that url.
method attribute should be as POST value

Comment: thank you Manmohan it worked i have not used method attribute, thanks alot ur suggestion helped.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should rename the controller name to Page.php (Make first letter capital). Your controller code should look like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('Page_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if ($_POST) 
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('qualification', 'Qualification', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('residential', 'Residential Address', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('clinic', 'Clinic Address', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone Number', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $data['page_title']         = 'Doctors Feedback';
                $data['base_url']           = $this->uri->segment_array();
                $this->view('doctors_form', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $name           = $this->input->post('name',TRUE);
                $qualification  = $this->input->post('qualification',TRUE);
                $age            = $this->input->post('age',TRUE);
                $date           = $this->input->post('date',TRUE);
                $residential    = $this->input->post('residential',TRUE);
                $clinic         = $this->input->post('clinic',TRUE);
                $email          = $this->input->post('email',TRUE);
                $mobile         = $this->input->post('mobile',TRUE);
                $phone          = $this->input->post('phone',TRUE);
                $comment        = $this->input->post('comment',TRUE);

                $data = array(
                    'name'          => $name , 
                    'qualification' => $qualification , 
                    'age'           => $age , 
                    'date'          => $date , 
                    'residential'   => $residential , 
                    'clinic'        => $clinic , 
                    'email'         => $email , 
                    'mobile'        => $mobile , 
                    'phone'         => $phone , 
                    'comment'       => $comment , 
                );

                // Further deal with model using this array
            }
        }
    }


}
```

In your view, you should use the codeigniter form open and close tag preferably instead of HTML .

```
<?php echo form_open('Controller_name/function_name'); ?>  // equivalent to <form action='url'>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>  // equivalent to </form>
```

In your case you don't have to write the function name in form_open tag. Just write the controller name because index function is loads by default.